# Zopim API: How get chats-history attached files?

Tags: api, zopim

[**Zopim API**](https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/chat/chats)

In the `history` block I can't find information about the attached file.

```
curl https://www.zopim.com/api/v2/chats \
  -v -u {email_address}:{password}
```

But the information about the attached files is here: **[Attachments](https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/core/attachments#attachments)**

I can't understand how attached files and chat history are tied to each other.

Please, help to solve this problem.